# HTML for adding a meta box (basic text field) to page editor?

Tags: custom-field, metabox, html, post-editor

I am following [this tutorial](https://paulund.co.uk/display-post-meta-box-on-specific-page-templates) from to add a meta box to pages of a certain page template.

Unfortunately the code omits the part on how to create the actual meta box on the page (the HTML).

The code in particular for context is:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_product_meta');
function add_product_meta()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'page-templates/product-page.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'product_meta', // $id
                'Product Information', // $title
                'display_product_information', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}

function display_product_information()
{
    // Add the HTML for the post meta
}
```

What should the HTML for a meta box (text input field) be?

Comment: Have you tried an input tag of type text? There are many full examples on the official documentation page for `add_meta_box`, the tutorial you were following is ~7/8 years old now, doesn't cover saving, and is incomplete, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: Oh thanks. I was particularly interested in only displaying meta box on a specific page template which is why I used it.